# Move Recyclerview Item position based on String

Tags: java, android, string, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview where I would like to sort specific items dependant on their String value. For example, if any of the buttons within the RecyclerView contain the String "Naked", this value gets moved to the top of the Recyclerview with all other instances containing "Naked" and any other text, also moved further up this list.

```
{
    public CategoryGridAdapter(List<String> items, OnListItemClickListener<String> listener)
    {
        super(items, listener);
    }

    @NonNull @Override
    public BaseViewHolder<String> onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_category, parent, false);
        return new CategoryGridViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder<? super String> holder, int position)
    {
        String item = getItem(position);
        holder.bind(item);
        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> getListener().onItemClick(item, holder.itemView));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pass the LayoutManger with constuctor

```
class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
        private LinearLayoutManager manager;

        public Adapter(LinearLayoutManager manager)
        {
            this.manager=manager;
        }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       if (holder.button.gettext().tostring().equals("Naked")
                        {manager.scrollToPosition(0);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to consider the ListAdapter class
[ListAdapter Sample and Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter)

You can then easily just sort your list using things like loops and then pass it to 
submitList(newList);

The ListAdapter then handles everything for you, you even get great animations for the moved positions. So you don't have to tell it which stuff in the list has changed, it finds it out itself.

[Youtube Tutorial for ListAdapter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPPMygGxiEo)

In your case you can then just manually sort the list for example using a Comperator and pass it to submitList each time something changes.